# Differentiate indexPath from static table's sections

Tags: swift, tableview

I can get the row number by `indexPath.row` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and different section are getting the same index like 0,1,2,3; 0,1; 0,1,2 ... How can I find out which section is being selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSIndexPath section property

```
indexPath.section
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the answer is so directly, since the suggestion by typing "indexPath." in Xcode not given the keyword to me. Thanks a lot!